# Using NSPredicate to search a 2D array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array, nspredicate

I want to use NSPredicate to search for a similar/matching string in an array of an array and return the array that contains the string.

Below is an example of the 2D array that I am wanting searched.

```
NSMutableArray *people [
   [@"Jane", @"Doe"],
   [@"John", @"Smith"]
]
```

Example: Searching "Jane" will return the array [@"Jane", @"Doe"]

Note: The inner arrays are NSMutableArray's, NOT NSArray's.

I tried using this code:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
searchResults = [people filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

but no results are shown no matter what I type and an alert that tells me the count of searchResults reports 0.

Comment: Your code worked for me (except that it returned an array with an array inside it, [[@"Jane", @"Doe"]], when the search string was "Jane").

Comment: As @rdelmar pointed out there is an error in your code somewhere else, because what you've provided works for me as well. What is `searchResults`? Is it supposed to be a property? Is it instantiated?

Comment: I ended up using the 2D array that you get using my code instead of breaking it into a 1D array. Thanks for the help though.